# TKinter how to configure all labels and buttons at once

Tags: button, tkinter, label, configure

Now, I'm writing a code to change all the buttons and labels color when a button is pressed.
But I get a different error every time.

```
windows = []
global windows
buttons = []
global buttons
labels = []
global labels
```

## A bunch of code... Then...

```
    def flavor(c):
    if c != 0:
        c = 0
        for w in windows:
            w.config(bg = 'black')
        for l in labels:
            l.config(bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
        for b in buttons:
            b.config(bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
    elif c != 1:
        c = 1
        for w in windows:
            w.config(bg = 'dark green')
        for l in labels:
            l.config(bg = 'dark green', fg = 'light green')
        for b in buttons:
            b.config(bg = 'dark green', fg = 'light green')
```

The error I got nearly all the time and most of time was :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\An interesting experiment\FOBBY.py", line 153, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\An interesting experiment\FOBBY.py", line 118, in main
thememenu.add_command(label="Plain",command = flavor(0))
File "C:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\An interesting experiment\FOBBY.py", line 79, in flavor
l.config(bg = 'dark green', fg = 'light green')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Thanks for help

Comment: How did you instantiate these buttons, labels and how did you put them into the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am willing to bet you are creating your widgets like this:

```
l = Label(,,,).pack(...)
labels.append(l)
```

When you do something like `foo().bar()`, the result is whatever the last function returns. In your case pack (or maybe grid) is the last function to be called and it always returns `None`. Thus, your lists contain nothing but `None`s.